# I want to see the current track playing in Amarok from the system tray

Tags: system-tray, amarok

Amarok sits in the system tray, and offers controls for the player.
However, to see what song is playing, I have to open the player itself. I cannot find how to, or if it is possible at all, to show the currently playing song.

[image: Amarok System Tray Interface]